# Constructor inside if-statement returns Uncaught Type error

Tags: javascript, if-statement, constructor

If I define the following constructor and method, I can call deck.tracker = new ActivityTracker();
without error:

```
function ActivityTracker() {}

    ActivityTracker.prototype = {
        trackEvent: function () {}
    }
```

If I add the code inside an if-statement (to limit the code to a local server):

```
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("http://0.0.0.0") == 0 || 
   window.location.href.indexOf('http://local') == 0) {

    function ActivityTracker() {}

    ActivityTracker.prototype = {
        trackEvent: function () {}
    }
};
```

the console returns: Uncaught TypeError: ActivityTracker is not a constructor.
I have made sure, that the if-condition returns true.

Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: Why not move the check inside of the activity tracker? The compiler/interpreter doesn't like that you are defining a function inside of an if statement that may not evaluate to true as it cannot properly bootstrap the function this way

Comment: Long story short: Just don't do that.

Comment: The ActivityTracker should only to be defined in local, but on the server it's part of the webapp and ActivityTracker is defined there in a different way. Any ideas how to solve this? function expressions don't work